# Is it possible to make an ActiveRecord model in RoR write-once and lock?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how to save an active record instance to the database and then lock it so that you can't write to it anymore (updates or saves), but you can still read from it.

I'd like to be able to do it upon creation in the model itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than overwriting the save method, I'd recommend you create a `before_update` hook that always returns false. From [the callback documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled

A `before_update` callback will be run only when attempting to save an already-existing record. When it's originally created, it will run `before_create` instead. With the hook, you can be sure it will be called no matter what method is used to save the record. When you overwrite the existing `save` method, you'll have to make sure that `save!`, `update_attributes`, etc. are all overwritten as well.